# iOS 13 AVAsset: mediaOptions on AVAssetCache returning empty array for audio and captions

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios13, avasset

We have an app that downloads assets and media selections using .aggregateAssetDownloadTask. In iOS 12.4 and below we have been able to access the captions tracks when offline using the asset's assetCache. On an iOS 13 device, the assetCache for the captions is now empty despite being downloaded. We can get the captions if we directly access the assets tracks using asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: characteristic).

We access the tracks like this:

```
guard let asset = currentItem.asset as? AVURLAsset else { return [] }
let cache = asset.assetCache
if let group = asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: characteristic), let languages = cache?.mediaSelectionOptions(in: group) {
     if medium == .captions {
          return languages.filter({ $0.hasMediaCharacteristic(AVMediaCharacteristic.containsOnlyForcedSubtitles) == false }).compactMap({ $0 as Language})
     } else {
          return languages
     }
}
```

We've filed a radar with apple but we're wondering if anyone else has ran into this issue? If so what workaround you're using? We're hesitant to access the mediaSelectionGroup on the asset.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. Did you find a solution or a workaround to this problem?
Or have you got any feedback from apple about this?

Comment: We ended up having to access the mediaSelectionGroup directly from the asset unfortunately. Apple responded to our radar at the end of September with "Potential fix identified - For a future OS update". Hopefully they'll release it soon!

Comment: Did you observe any side-effects of doing so?

Comment: We haven't noticed anything negative.